# Website functioning in an android web view

Tags: android, ios, webview, native

I have an online shopping website that i have made responsive enough to appear as an app(still a website) in mobile devices.I am thinking of moving to its app development for android and ios.The most important thing in mind right now is that should i integrate the website as a web-view or should i develop a complete new native app for it in android and ios.Wanted to know the advantages and disadvantages of using webview with javascript enabled and developing a completely new native app for it.What are the things that i miss or achieve in both theses ideas!!
Need suggestion immediately.Please help.Thank you in advance.:-)

Answer (score 0):

Of course a native app is better. Though it's development will be complex because you'll need to make REST api for getting , posting data to your website database. And the app will use that api to communicate with your site.

Loading your website in a webview is a matter of 15 Minutes. But think , webview doesn't support all features of web browser , so why people use your app with low feature , instead they can use their web browser.